# Blogger meta property (facebook, twitter, google+)

Tags: facebook, twitter, blogger

Are there any possible way to add a meta property such as different image size for each social networking site? I know this is achievable by meta tag, but how can I define it for each blog posts? like I'll just upload the other sizes in imgur? As far as I know, the meta property is loaded in the head part of the page right? So it can't be manipulated or changed while writing/posting an article

Answer (score 0):

@Confur Quod: Blogger doesn't works as a dynamic site. You can do this in only dynamic sites.

But you can add commonly used meta tags to your blogger.

Add this code to after `<head>` tag

```
<meta content='FB_APP_ID' property='fb:app_id'/>
<meta content='FB_ID' property='fb:admins'/>
<link href='GOOGLE+_PROFILE_LINK' rel='author'/>
<link href='GOOGLE+_PROFILE_LINK' rel='publisher'/>
<meta content='YOUR_NAME' name='creator'/>
<meta content='AUTHOR_NAME' name='author'/>
<meta content='@TWITTER_USERNMAE' name='twitter:creator'/>
<meta content='@TWITTER_USERNMAE' name='twitter:site'/>
<meta content='https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME' property='article:author'/>
<meta content='https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME' property='article:publisher'/>
```